# Celery - identify the tasks of another chain in a chain

Tags: python-2.7, celery, python-3.5, django-celery, celery-task

I have stepA and stepB which needs to be applied to ~100 sets of data. Since these sets are CPU intensive I want them to happen sequentially.

I am using Celery to create a chain with ~100 chains with (stepA and StepB).

It celery execution works fine, I want to show the status of each of the chain in a django page as each of the stepA and stepB may take an hour to complete.

I want to show the status of each of the sub chains in a django page. The problem is the `AsyncResult` sees all the children of the parent chain as tasks. 
The following is a sample code snippet.

> test_celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
from celery import Celery, chord, chain, group
from datetime import datetime
import time
app = Celery('tasks', backend='redis', broker='redis://')


@app.task
def ident(x):
    print("Guru: inside ident: {}".format(datetime.now()))
    print(x)
    return x


@app.task
def tsum(numbers):
    print("Guru: inside tsum: {}".format(datetime.now()))
    print(numbers)
    time.sleep(5)
    return sum(numbers)
```

> test.py

```
import test_celery
from celery import chain
from celery.result import AsyncResult
from celery.utils.graph import DependencyGraph

def method():
    async_chain = chain(chain(test_celery.tsum.si([1, 2]), test_celery.ident.si(2)), chain(test_celery.tsum.si([2,3]), test_celery.ident.si(3)))

    chain_task_names = [task.task for task in async_chain.tasks]
    # run the chain
    chain_results_tasks = async_chain.apply_async()


    print("async_chain=", dir(chain_results_tasks))
    print("result.get={}".format(chain_results_tasks.status))
    # create a list of names and tasks in the chain
    chain_tasks = zip(chain_task_names, reversed(list(get_chain_nodes(chain_results_tasks))))
    xx = list(get_chain_nodes(chain_results_tasks))

    #
    print(dir(chain_results_tasks))

    for task in async_chain.tasks:
        print("dir task={}".format(dir(task)))
        print("task_name={} task_id={}".format(task.task, task.parent_id))

    for i in xx:
        res = AsyncResult(i)
        # print("res={}".format(dir(res)))
        parent = get_parent_node(i)
        print(parent.build_graph(intermediate=True))
        print("parent_task={}".format(dir(parent)))
    print(xx[-1].build_graph(intermediate=True))


method()
```

Any help is appreciated.